# Open terminal with git fail: why?

Tags: macos, git, terminal

need help. When I open mac terminal I got such error:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 10 10:06:27 on ttys000
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
my_name:~$
```

And after is everything is fine.
This error occurred in folders which are NON git repo.
If folder is git repo, than no any errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes: you have some sort of shell startup item (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.shrc`, whatever) that runs a `git` command.  It runs this command even if you're not in a repository.  In that case, the git command fails.  Fix your shell startup item to either not run the git command at all, or hide its errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your shell initialization files (like `~/.bash_profile`) to see if you haven't modified the prompt (`PS1`) in order to add information about git repo.
See for example this blog "[Add Git Branch Name to Terminal Prompt (Mac)](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/)"

```
parse_git_branch() {

    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'

}

export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

As you can see, the git command **redirect stderr to /dev/null**: this is enough to avoid the error message you see.

The OP confirms having found the issue:

```
alias gitDel="git rm git status | grep deleted | awk '{print \$2}'"
# should be
alias gitDel="git rm git status 2> /dev/null | grep deleted | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

Comment: This is my PS1 param in .bash_profile `export PS1="\u:\W$ "`

Comment: @Serhey as torek commented (I didn't see it when writing my answer), check for other  shell startup items.

Comment: How can I check it, can you give an advice?

Comment: @Serhey `cd ~;grep git .*` is a start: look for `git` in any .* files.

Comment: Add this function you wrote, but didn't help ((

Comment: @Serhey did you look for your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, and other `.xxx` files in your home dir?

Comment: .bashrc is clean. .bash_profile contains only alises

Comment: @Serhey check also system-wide initialization files: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html

Comment: Found out the problem alias `alias gitDel="git rm `git status | grep deleted | awk '{print \$2}'`"`

Comment: Is any idea how to rewrite this alias in proper way?

Comment: @Serhey how about the part of my answer which is in bold? I have edited the answer.

Comment: I think @Serhey has a literal backquote in his alias, and backquotes are evaluated in double quotes.  I don't normally use bash so don't want to try to come up with a "best fix", but the most obvious thing to do is write a shell function, rather than an alias, here.

Comment: @torek true, but I don't see any backquote in the alias copied by the OP.

Comment: There's some font changes that would occur if he cut-and-pasted something and surrounded the whole paste with backquotes, which is why I think they're in there.  (Comment formatting is pretty primitive)